# What class of cleaning/detailing products do I use for artificial/imitation leather?

Tags: cleaning, detailing, plastic, leather, rubber

I just bought a Tesla Model 3, and it's full of artificial leather (seats, dash, doors, center console...)

When browsing car detailing/maintenance stores, I find 2 separate "classes" of cleaners and shampoos:

- Plastic, rubber, vinyl
- Leather

Should I be using products intended for leather, or products intended for plastic/rubber/vinyl?

There are *no* products I can find that mentions artificial leather.

---

The manual doesn't help much, except I now know the artificial leather on the seats is called "Polyurethane":

> ### Dashboard and Plastic Surfaces
>
> Do not polish the upper surfaces of the
>   dashboard. Polished surfaces are reflective
>   and could interfere with your driving view.
>
> ### Polyurethane Seats
>
> Wipe spills as soon as possible using a soft
>   cloth moistened with warm water and nondetergent soap. Wipe gently in a circular
>   motion. After cleaning, allow the seats to air
>   dry.

[Tesla Model 3 Owner's Manual](https://www.tesla.com/sites/default/files/model_3_owners_manual_north_america_en.pdf), page 163

Comment: What does your manual say?

Comment: @SolarMike That didn't occur to me to check. I added an excerpt to the question. It doesn't help much.

Comment: That actually seems very clear. Good safety tip with don't make the dash shiny, and clear instructions of how to clean the seats - what more could you want - except for someone else to do it for you...

Comment: @SolarMike I didn't say it wasn't clear, but it doesn't help much in answering the question I asked.

Comment: Warm water and nondetergent soap. Unless you have some nondetergent soap then you need to go shopping.

Answer (score 2):

Artificial "leather" is a plastic-like material.

I'd use a cleaner for plastic/rubber/vinyl and not an actual leather product.

You might check the Owner's Manual and see if they recommend a specific type of product or an actual product recommendation.

Comment: I added an excerpt to the question from the "Cleaning" section of the manual that mentions the dashboard and seats. The seat material is polyurethane, if that helps. They don't recommend any specific type of cleaning product, just that it should be "nondetergent".